Question about Cartan's Theory of Spinors, Section 53 a spinor is a Euclidean tensor
Context
I'm studying spinors in detail as part of research project. I'm working through
Cartan's Theory of Spinors [1]. In section 53, A spinor is a Euclidean tensor, Cartan asks us to, "Consider a rotation (or reversal)" defined by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^\prime
\\
x_2^\prime
\\
x_3^\prime
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{11}
&
R_{12}
&
R_{13}
\\
R_{21}
&
R_{22}
&
R_{23}
\\
R_{31}
&
R_{32}
&
R_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 
\\
x_2 
\\
x_3 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In Section 53 (pg 42), Cartan states that
$$
(R_{11} -iR_{21})^2 + (R_{12} -iR_{22})^2 + (R_{13} -iR_{23})^2 = 0.
$$
I had no idea that this was a property of rotation (or reveral) matrices.
I verified that this is true for an arbitrary from axis-angle rotation matrix [2], $R_\text{rot}$, where
$$
R_\text{rot}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \theta +u_x^2 \left(1-\cos \theta\right) & u_x u_y \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_z \sin \theta & u_x u_z \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_y \sin \theta \\ 
u_y u_x \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_z \sin \theta & \cos \theta + u_y^2\left(1-\cos \theta\right) & u_y u_z \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_x \sin \theta \\ 
u_z u_x \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_y \sin \theta & u_z u_y \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_x \sin \theta & \cos \theta + u_z^2\left(1-\cos \theta\right)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
However, I have not verified this for reflections, or improper rotations.
Question
Can you prove that each and every element of the orthogonal group (that I believe to  include proper rotations, improper rotations, and reflections) has the property
$$
(R_{11} -iR_{21})^2 + (R_{12} -iR_{22})^2 + (R_{13} -iR_{23})^2 = 0?
$$
Bibliography
[1] Cartan, The Theory of Spinors, 1966, p 42.
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Examples_2

Cartan wrote
\begin{align}
x_1'&=\alpha x_1+\beta x_2+\gamma x_3\,,\\
x_2'&=\alpha' x_1+\beta' x_2+\gamma' x_3\,,\\
x_3'&=\alpha'' x_1+\beta'' x_2+\gamma'' x_3\,,\\
\end{align}
and
$$\tag2
(\alpha-i\alpha')^2+(\beta-i\beta')^2+(\gamma-i\gamma')^2=0
$$
which in your notation is
$$
(R_{11}-iR_{21})^2+(R_{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{12}}}^2-iR_{22})^2+(R_{13}-iR_{23})^3=0\,.
$$
(I highlighted where I fixed a typo of yours).
The equation (2) is obvious because the rows of the matrix are orthonormal
so that (2) can be written as
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}_{1}-\underbrace{\left(\alpha'\,^2+\beta'\,^2+\gamma'\,^2\right)}_{1}-2i\underbrace{(\alpha\alpha'+\beta\beta'+\gamma\gamma')}_{0}=0\,.
\end{align}
